# Why is angularjs expect don't working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I tried to write the simplest possible javascript unit test with ***angular.js*** but it fails and I don't know why.

test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular-1.2.21/angular-scenario.js" ng-autotest></script>
    <script src="test1.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

test1.js

```
describe('A suite', function() {
  it('should be true', function() {
    expect(5).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

I deploy both files (and libs) on server and call the html site. The tests runs but always fails with

```
expected undefined toBe 5 but was undefined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: any console error? have you loaded the angular app in the test suite?

Comment: no console errors, for trying I added also the app and some controller but I didn't expect that I need them for such a small test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information that you have given I think you have not included the jasmine file

```
http://searls.github.io/jasmine-all/jasmine-all-min.js
```

Tried your code after including this and it is working fine.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnv7g/)

Comment: You're using the jasmine runner. I tried to use the angular runner.

Comment: as per angular docs https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/guide/e2e-testing it is deprecated. The docs also mention that they use Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is wrong. Try:

```
 expect(5).to.equal(5);
```

REF: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: Seems to be another framework, I tried to use the angular test runner.